# What does 'reduced the importance' mean in context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'reduced the importance' mean? Is it good or bad? Good probably if it is an ad but why?

> Apple has already **reduced the importance** of iTunes on the iPhone and
>   iPad and will now do the same on Mac computers too. iTunes will still
>   be available on Macs using older OS versions, as well as on machines
>   running Microsoft’s Windows system.

VOA article: Apple to Add New Software, Privacy Tool, End iTunes

Comment: It's just the dictionary definitions of "reduce" and "importance".  You have to read the article to understand (or at least infer) *how* they are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's the simple meanings of the words.

If they "reduce the importance" of something it used to be important, and now it is less so.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the [dictionary definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/to-make-something-seem-less-important-or-special) of the expression, shall we?

> To reduce the importance of something:
>
> > To make something seem less important or special

Now on to the sentence:

> Apple has already reduced the importance of iTunes on the iPhone and iPad

This means that they used to put a lot of importance on iTunes but they have made it less important.

Let's look at more examples to make things more clear: (Ludwig.guru)

> Ministers' plans **to reduce the importance of** income in measuring child poverty are today sharply criticized by their own official adviser on child poverty.
>
> Beijing has announced a proposal to reduce the importance of English on the college entrance examination taken by high school students.  (so the Chinese officials want to make English less important on the test)

was this helpful?